# wso2carbon Identity Server SSO redirect to port 9443

Tags: saml-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using wso2 IS 4.8.0, my problem is that when I use the SAML2 SSO, I'm beeing redirect to port 9443 on the browser.

I want to be redirected to another port: 80 or 443, because there is an apache that proxies everything.

Is there a configuration to point the rediret to these ports?

Comment: The latest release version WSO2 Identity Server is 4.6.0. Currently 4.7.0 version is under development and latest milestone release is M2.

Comment: Please always remember to read the helpful descriptions that appear when selecting tags, and *always* search the tag list carefully for relevant tag names.  You missed a few...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding **proxyPort** to `catalina-server.xml` which can be found at `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/tomcat` folder as follows,

```
<Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
            port="9443"
            proxyPort="443"
```

And you'll need to change redirect url of ssoservice as well which can be found in `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/identity.xml` file. Find for `<SSOService>` tag and edit `<IdentityProviderURL>` like follows,

```
<IdentityProviderURL>https://localhost:443/samlsso</IdentityProviderURL>
```

---

**EDIT** : Better to **use IdentityProviderURL without the default port**.

```
<IdentityProviderURL>https://localhost/samlsso</IdentityProviderURL>
```

Since 443 is the default port and there might be validation fails when it redirect to url with port and original request sent without the port.

---

HTH,

DarRay.